# No cargan las imágenes en chrome pero si en internet explorer en el debug

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un problema y he buscado por todo lado pero no encuentro nada al respecto.

El caso es que en mi programa cargo unas imágenes que viene de un servidor y cuando hago el *debug* en mi navegador de Internet Explorer me muestra la imagen correctamente, pero cuando lo hago por Google Chrome no la muestra pero si se puede descargar dando clic derecho.

```
<img src="@ViewBag.ImageData" alt="No se encuentra la imagen" style="width:90%" id="ImagenTapa" class="w3-animate-zoom" />
```

¿Cómo podría resolver este problema?

Comment: si usas el developer tools del browser al cual accedes con F12 podrias analizar con la solapa network si esta resolviendo correctamente la url de la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando asignas una imagen directo al `src` deberias hacerlo encodeando esta a base64

[6.1. Imágenes embebidas](http://librosweb.es/libro/css_avanzado/capitulo_6.html)

para que funcione correctamente deberias asegurarte que indicas el `mediatype`

```
<img src=”data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS… (see source for full base64 encoded image) …8bgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=”>
```

el `data:image/png` es importante indicarlo

Comment: en el controlador hago esa parte que tu me dices:  string imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}",imageBase64Data);  en el developer del navegador:  src="data:image/png;base64,SUAAA..  Pero aun así sigue sin mostrarme la imagen que mas podría revisar?